# Counting rows with some constrain in PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql, group-by, aggregate

I have a Table

[image: Schema]

I want to count the number of wickets taken by a bowler in a single match, I know this is a trivial query but I am pretty much stuck here.
there are matches with unique id and in every match there is a wicket taken by a bowler(id) in over(over_id) and on ball no(ball_id) , A bowler can bowl several over and can take wickets in these over , I wanted to aggregate the number of wickets taken in particular match

Its solved in comments

Comment: You can do a select query. Your question needs some knowledge of bowling, such as what is a wicket. Assuming it is something like "amount", you could simply do something like: select sum(wickets) from myTable where match_id = 335987 and bowler = 82;

Comment: Actually I want to count wickets for every match not single fixed match,like match-335987, bowler-82,wicket_taken-3 similar for all match and bowler combination

Comment: Then add group by. It is part of SQL elementary which you can check on w3schools.com. Select match_id, bowler, sum(wickets) as totalWickets from myTable group by match_id, bowler;

BTW here pay attention to provide sample data in text rather than a picture.

Comment: Thank you very much thats what I wanted, I was really stuck here and not able to figure this out.

Comment: @Cetin A little bit more information, If I want to return player_name instead of bowler_id , which is stored in another table with player_name and player_id , I am trying a join with mytable.bowler = player_detail.player_id, one possibility was making a function which will return player_name with input player_id , but we are allowed to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to write this as an answer as it is getting a mess in comments:

```
select p.player_id, p.player_name, t.match_id, t.wickets
from player_detail p 
inner join
(Select match_id, bowler, sum(wickets) as totalWickets 
 from myTable group by match_id, bowler) t ON p.player_id = t.bowler
order by p.player_name, t.match_id;
```